# Changing timeframe in query from 'now' to a specific date in Dune Analytics

Tags: sql

how can I change the "now () - interval '365days'" to a "specific date () - interval '365 days'"? thank you

```
select avg(usd_volume) from
(
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', block_time) AS day,
    SUM(usd_amount) AS usd_volume
FROM dex.trades
WHERE block_time > now() - interval '365days'
AND project = 'Curve'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
)x
```

Comment: Please also specify which RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

you can type in the date you want and cast it to date type, something like this

```
'2022-08-21'::DATE - interval '365days'
```